# eslint semi rule: why is there a "2" in the rule config?

Tags: javascript, eslint

ESLint says to use this config to enforce semicolons.

```
semi: [2, "always"]
```

What is the meaning of the 2?

Comment: It's the severity of a rule violation.

Answer (score 1):

As [the docs say](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/rules), for each rule, you can have:

> - "off" or 0 - turn the rule off
> - "warn" or 1 - turn the rule on as a warning (doesn't affect exit code)
> - "error" or 2 - turn the rule on as an error (exit code is 1 when triggered)

So the 2 tells ESLint to treat violations of the rule as an error.

You could, equivalently, do

```
semi: ['error', "always"]
```

which might make more sense at a glance.